# I'm having trouble opening .dmg files

Tags: files

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS & I'm having trouble opening .dmg files. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to open a **Mac OS X** disk on a **Linux** operating system? You could try to open it with file roller.

Comment: Because I wanna play an online game which is downloaded in .dmg form.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to run a Mac OS X executable on Linux. Even though Mac OS, using BSD, is closer related to Linux than Windows is, the binaries are most likely incompatible. You could try to use the Windows version of the game and run it with WineHQ.